# best way for substring pandas data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas, feature-extraction, kaggle

### Q1

I want to extract the Title of each person from the `Name` attribute of `concat` data frame. what is the best way of doing this?

```
concat['Title'][concat['Title'] == 'Mlle'] = 'Miss'
concat['Title'][concat['Title'] == 'Ms'] = 'Miss'
concat['Title'][concat['Title'] == 'Mme'] = 'Mrs'
concat['Title'][concat['Title'] == 'Dona' or 'Lady'or 'Countess'or'Capt' or 'Col'or'Don'or 'Dr'or 'Major'or 'Rev'or 'Sir'or 'Jonkheer' ] = 'Rare'
```

### Q2

when i run the above code i get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

why?

---

### Refrences

the full problem with datasets : [Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), and then extract the second item from the resultant list.

```
In [37]: df['Name'].head()
Out[37]: 
0                              Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1    Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...
2                               Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
3         Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)
4                             Allen, Mr. William Henry
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

An observation here is that names follow this format: *Last Name*, *Salutation* *Given Name*. We'll split on spaces and extract the *Salutation* from the split lists using `df.apply`:

```
In [38]: df['Title'] = df['Name'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x[1])

In [39]: df['Title'].head()
Out[39]: 
0      Mr.
1     Mrs.
2    Miss.
3     Mrs.
4      Mr.
Name: Title, dtype: object
```

Comment: I love your solution but it's not general! if we have a `Name` in the middle of data that don't follow this format: Last Name, Salutation ...

Comment: @KouchakYazdi A more general solution would involve using `df['Name'].str.extract(....)`  // with some regex. I leave that to you :)

Answer (score 0):

What does "extract" mean is not clear.

Does the following help?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1 , 'title' : 'mrs'},
                  {'id': 2 , 'title' : 'mr'},
                  {'id': 3 , 'title' : 'mr'},
                  {'id': 4 , 'title' : 'mrs'}])

df[df.title == 'mrs']
#   id title
#0   1   mrs
#3   4   mrs

df[((df.title == 'mrs') | (df.title == 'mr'))]
#   id title
#0   1   mrs
#1   2    mr
#2   3    mr
#3   4   mrs
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the Mr. Mrs. Miss. Capt. Master from the name feature of the dataset

```
for _ in data:
data['Title'] = dataset['Name'].str.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand = False)
```

Comment: Heisenberg27, I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please [edit] and add an explanation how this works and why it is supposed to help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it only describes, without explaining.

Comment: What is the expand = False part doing?